# Why is my post route not running properly in Express app?

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I am trying to add a route to '/signup' in my express application. But, every time I am sending a post request to the server it is resolving in "No response". Whereas the '/' route is working. Where have I gone wrong with the code?

> index.js

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import morgan from "morgan";
import dbConnect from "./config/dbConnect.js";
import { authRoute } from "./routes/auth.js";

dotenv.config();
const port = process.env.PORT;
const DATABASE_URI = process.env.DATABASE_URI;
const app = express();

dbConnect();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("combined"));

app.use("/api/v1", authRoute);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at ${port}...`);
});
```

> auth.js

```
import { Router } from "express";

const router = Router();

router.post("signup", (req, res) => {
    const password = req.body.password;
    console.log(password);
});

export { router as authRoute };
```

> dbConnect.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const DATABASE_URI = process.env.DATABASE_URI;

const dbConnect = () => {
    mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
    mongoose
        .connect(DATABASE_URI)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("connected");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
};

export default dbConnect;
```

Comment: You never returned a response using `res.send("content")` in **auth.js**.

Comment: I tried using res.sendStatus(200). Still it is not working!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> router.post("signup", (req, res) => {
>     const password = req.body.password;
>     console.log(password);
> });
> ```

The client doesn't get a response because you haven't written any code to send a response.

You completely ignore the object passed to `res`.

You don't call `res.json` or `res.render` or `res.send` or any of the other methods that would send a response.

Comment: I have tried res.sendStatus(200)! Still there is no response from the server!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was with my VSCode extension RapidApi client, tried using insomnia and it worked out fine. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Sound like a comment, not an answer

Comment: Actually the problem was happening only because I was using the Rapid Api VSCode client